# How to make jQuery click() function only run once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scenario where I want an event to happen when a button is clicked, but then I want a different behavior when it's clicked the second time. Here's an example of what's happening:

```js
$('.click').not('.clicked').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
    $('<p class="test">Test</p>').insertAfter(this);
});
```

```css
.clicked {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' class="click" value="Click Me" />
<input type='button' class="click clicked" value="Click Me" />
<input type='button' class="click" value="Click Me" />
```

What I want it to do is stop running the jQuery once the class `.clicked` is added to the button. This works the way I would expect, if the button already has the class applied, but if I add the class with jQuery it doesn't stop running my function each time the button is clicked.

Comment: Why not use `$('.click').one()` instead ...?

Comment: use $(".click:not(.clicked)")

Comment: @Liquidchrome I believe this wouldn't work because the event listener would be already bound to the elements when a second click is made.

Comment: @Circle B Please accept the answer when applicable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not matter which type of CSS selector you use because it will be executed only once. So you are adding an event listener for every tag with the class `.click` and without `.clicked`. You should do something like this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.click:not(.clicked)', function () {
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
    $('<p class="test">Test</p>').insertAfter(this);
});
```

```css
.clicked {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' class="click" value="Click Me" />
<input type='button' class="click clicked" value="Click Me" />
<input type='button' class="click" value="Click Me" />
```

Adding the event listener to the whole document and later selecting the tags using `.click:not(.clicked)` allows you to "evaluate" the css selector every single time.

Comment: Great answer indeed, but why make it so over-cooked? It is completely unnecessary to inject a class when we only need the event handler to work once. The code just becomes difficult to read and harder to maintain.  But in a review, it will look much more complicated and badass, I admit that. Job security by code obscurity :)

Comment: @davidkonrad I've supposed that this is a minimun and verificable example of a bigger problem. But as you said, only reading the title, it would be much better with `one`.

Comment: @Diego You're the man! The rest of the project (and the reason why I'm wanting to have the `clicked` class) is that I'm wanting to be able to change styles, behavior and such after clicking. Then I'll remove that class when I click on another one.